# Algorithm to answer questions on dominated input

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Consider a setting where we see inputs one-by-one, with each input being an $n$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, where each $a_i\in\{0,1\}$. For each new input we see, we have to answer two questions:

1) Have we seen this input before?

2) Is the input *dominated* by some input we've seen before? (An input $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is said to be *dominated* by an input $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ if $a_i\leq b_i$ for all $i$.)

How fast can we answer these two questions for each input?

For question 1), we can use a hash table. We check whether the input has been seen before in $O(1)$ time, and if not, insert the input into the hash table in $O(1)$ time.

To accommodate question 2), the trivial way is to compare the new input with each one of the previous inputs, which would take $O(k)$ time, where $k$ is the number of elements in the hash table. This could be up to $O(2^n)$ time. Is there a way to reduce this to something polynomial in $n$?

Comment: Hashing the tuple requires $O(n)$ time right? so the first case cannot be $O(1)$ unless $n$ is constant.

Also, for the second one, do you mean $O(k \times n)$ (compare to every other $k$ element, and each comparison is $O(n)$)

Comment: @Irvan Hashing each tuple requires $O(1)$ time. (Remember we're considering the time to answer the questions for **each** input.)

Comment: But each input is $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$, i.e., consists of $n$ elements right? Thus, if $H$ is the hashing function, $H(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ takes at least $O(n)$.

Comment: @Irvan You can think of each input as an integer between $1$ and $2^n$ (that is, consider $a_1a_2\ldots a_n$ as the representation in base $2$.) Then it only takes (average-case) $O(1)$ time to [insert it into a hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we treat each $n$-tuple as a subset of $1,2,\ldots, n$ in the natural way, then we see that $A$ dominates $B$ if $B$ is a subset of $A$. The paper ["New Algorithms for Subset Query, Partial Match, Orthogonal Range Searching and Related Problems" (pdf)](http://web.mit.edu/~jfc/tmp/subset%20queries.pdf) by Charikar, Indyk, and Panigrahy presents some time/space tradeoff results for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I 'll take it you mean $a_i\in (0,1)$ not $\{0,1\}$ because this is a binary string. Non the less, what I am thinking apllies to both cases.

Since you get your tuples one by one we will sort them with an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) algorithm a little modified to sort the tuples [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) . This is like a dictionary, e.g. $(1, 0.5, 0.4) \geq (1, 0.6, 1)\geq(0.9, 1,0.6)$ because: $0.5<0.6$.

Leaving the details,
**1)** when a tuple is sorted in its place it can only be identical with the ones adjacent to it, which is easy to check.
**2)** Starting from the last tuple and going up, check if each tuple is dominated by its previous. If $A$ and $B$ are two tuples and $A$ dominates $B$ then for sure $a_1\geq b_1$ and $A\geq B$, $A$ must be greater than $B$ to dominate $B$.

The overall time of insertion sort is $O(n^2)$ and the checks can be performes in linear time after the inputs are sorted.

Comment: I actually meant $a_i\in\{0,1\}$, and hence $a_1a_2\ldots a_n$ is a binary string. Using your algorithm, each check can indeed be performed in linear time, which could be up to $2^n$ (since there could be up to $2^n$ distinct binary strings of length $n$). My question was whether we can do better than this.